# How to address this instance of C4428 Visual C++ warning about a character literal?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, constants, literals

Currently Visual C++ issues [C4428](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw8abkd.aspx) warning

> universal-character-name encountered in source

on the following code

```
const wchar_t someMagicValue = L'\ufffd';
```

I'd like to address this warning and I wonder whether the following:

```
const wchar_t someMagicValue = L'\xfffd';
```

will be fully equivalent code.

Will the latter code be fully equivalent to the former? What could be a better option?

Comment: Maybe you should use the [`#pragma`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to suppress the warning since you wrote what you intended and want it to be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

As commented here

[Compiler Warning (level 4) C4428 (VS2010)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw8abkd.aspx)

this is most likely /just a bug/ in MSVC

See also [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/13ecfe21-d767-4e01-9092-3fd0eedd5675) for a bit more discussion

Comment: Will changing code as I suggest produce fully equivalent code?

Comment: @sharptooth: I wouldn't trust that (it will at least depend on the declaration of wchar_t and the endianness of the machine you compile this on). I'd simply silence the warning and track any open bug reports here http://connect.microsoft.com/

Comment: How could you have given >1k of answers, earning >18k of rep without knowing the most basic things about markdown formatting on SO??

Comment: @sehe: Visual C++ does not compile for machines with varying endiannesses and with different definitions of `wchar_t`.

Comment: @sehe: I wonder how endianness would influence a constant literal.

Comment: @sharptooth: it might not change a thing, but I wouldn't be too sure. Regardless, your **intent** is to specify a unicode code point, not? I'd always vote code that expresses the intent

Comment: @sbi: ftfy    - note you are free to fix it; I was in a hurry

Comment: @sehe: Note that I _did_ fix it. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
const wchar_t someMagicValue = 0xfffd;
```

Comment: I could try this, but I want to be completely sure I don't break code.

Comment: Well, wchar_t on Windows is just a 16 bit unsigned int. You can put any value you like in there as a number. You can do the same with char: `char ch = 0x20;` will leave `ch` containing a space. It's exactly the same as doing `char ch = ' ';`