# What's the purpose of the "universal-character-name encountered in source" warning?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, literals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to address this instance of C4428 Visual C++ warning about a character literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078013/how-to-address-this-instance-of-c4428-visual-c-warning-about-a-character-liter)

If I compile the code:

```
wchar_t c = L'\u00A0';
```

with the /W4 flag, I get the warning:

> Warning C4428: universal-character-name encountered in source

What I'm failing to understand is, what's the purpose of this warning? What mistake is it trying to prevent?

Comment: This looks relevant, but not particularly useful for the rvalue there. You might find it interesting, though: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2006/04/21/580316.aspx. Maybe it's suggesting to use the actual character for that, too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078013/how-to-address-this-instance-of-c4428-visual-c-warning-about-a-character-liter

Comment: That looks like the dumbest warning I've seen yet, to be honest. From reading things, it literally seems to have no point.

Comment: There's a [`#pragma`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for suppressing specific warnings, is there not?  This might be the time to use it (with an appropriately sarcastic comment about why it should not be necessary).  Perhaps the trouble is that (this tiny part of) Microsoft is a US company and doesn't really think there's world outside the USA that needs 'funny' characters.

Comment: Encoding of universal-character-names is implementation defined.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really about mistakes.

To my understanding, the warning merely tells you that you've used the character code instead of the actual character. For most characters that's merely a matter of making things more readable, although in your case, the character will look the same as a normal space so using the code is actually a good idea (or even better, I like to make macros or enums with the unicode names, so it would be NO_BREAK_SPACE).

Either way, one could debate to no end whether the warning is actually useful for anything. Or you could just disable that particular one (there are probably more warnings you've already disabled, like the one about unused inlines etc.) and go on.